# Openpyxl is not saving the excel file, why?

Tags: python, openpyxl

here is my code:

```
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import worksheet

path = ...
op.load_workbook(path)
wb = Workbook()

ws2 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet2')
wb.save(filename = 'NameOfTheFile.xlsx')
```

Now everything works, except saving the file, when I add:

`print(wb.sheetnames)`

it does print out the Sheet2 I just added, but for some reason when I go to the documents where the file is, it does not update it, that sheet is nowhere to be found.

Comment: You opened the workbook but didn't use it and just created a new `Workbbok`... Change to `wb = op.load_workbook(path)`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo oh.. thank you!